# Displaying errors in Zend 2 framework using PHP 7

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have set the following to index.php file in zend:

`error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

but it's still not showing the actual error. It says there:

`An error occurred
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.`

I also set the display_errors to `On` in the php.ini file and restart the server but still the error is not showing. Do you have any idea why is this happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you try use:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```